# Why any event (e.g Changing QLabel or QPushButton's Text) is reverting moved widget to it's first position in the Layout?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

I have extended a class from QpushButton in my Qt Program that overrides mousepress & mousemove events and cause the parent widget to move with left mouse click in the layout. but when I change some widget's properties in parent widget for example QLabel's text or QpushButton's text ,the parent widget goes back to it's original position in the layout , what's wrong with my code & how can I prevent this ?
any help is appreciated

here is My code :

```
MainWidget::MainWidget(QWidget *parent)
   : QWidget(parent)
   , ui(new Ui::MainWidget)
{
   ui->setupUi(this);

   MoveButton *movebut = new MoveButton(this);
   ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(movebut);

   connect(movebut , &MoveButton::positionChanged , ui->widgetMove , [this](const QPoint &newPos){
       ui->widgetMove->move(ui->widgetMove->mapToParent(newPos));
       currentPos = mapToParent(newPos);;
   });
}

MainWidget::~MainWidget()
{
   delete ui;
}

MoveButton::MoveButton(QWidget *parent) : QPushButton(parent)
{
   setText("Draggable Button");
   setMouseTracking(true);
   setContentsMargins(0 , 0 , 0 , 0);
   setMaximumHeight(30);
}

QSize MoveButton::minimumSizeHint() const
{
   return QSize(100 ,30);
}

void MoveButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
   if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
   {
       offset = event->pos();
       qDebug() << offset;
   }
}

void MoveButton::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
   //this->setCursor(Qt::OpenHandCursor);
   if(event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
   {
       emit positionChanged(event->pos() - offset);
   }
}

void MainWidget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   ui->pushButton->setText("Clicked");
}
```

[image: Initial State]

[image: After Dragging]

[image: After Clicking]

I have removed all spacers , but I have this issue again

Comment: A layout is responsible for positioning and sizing widgets.  The layout will update when certain events occur and resize and reposition all items in the layout according to the layout's rules.  If you are going to position widgets yourself, then don't use a layout.

Comment: @paddy thanks dude, it helped me a lot ,I think i must morph the widget to my custom widget without any layout